# Is FindFirstFile and FindNextFile order random? Even for dvd?

Tags: winapi, dvd

I expect that it depends on the filesystem used. I'm curious if I can make FindFirstFile FindNextFile feed me files in the order I want, by writing files on the disk in the specific order.

I guess I could try it on iso + iso emulator.

Also read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1269825/what-app-can-write-files-on-dvd-in-a-specific-order-and-other-issues).

Comment: They retrieve the names in the order they're stored on disk, which may not be in the order they were created in. With NTFS they're stored in alphabetical (Unicode) order. ISO 9960 requires that directories on disk be stored in alphabetical order. I don't think UDF does, but DVD mastering software may sort directories anyways.

Comment: The order depends entirely on the implementation of the filesystem. WinAPI `FindFirstFile` calls the native [`NtQueryDirectoryFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567047) system function, for which the I/O Manager invokes the driver's [`IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548658) routine with an `IRP_MN_QUERY_DIRECTORY` request. The filesystem device stack can handle this request however it wants.

Answer (score 0):

You will often get files sorted by their filename in uppercase.  A-Z and a-z will appear before _.  This is not guaranteed or specified anywhere.